# Developing GWT without a net connection?

Tags: gwt

When I'm developing my gwt project without a network connection, is there a way to detect this? For example, I have a widget that has an Image in it, and the widget does not display until the Image url request times out (takes a long time, like 2 minutes?).

Also, whenever I refresh the page in hosted mode, it doesn't finish loading for about a minute, when no network connection - seems like gwt is trying to contact some external website and blocking on that until it times out too - making things really slow - any way to stop that too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gwt-2.1.1, and I haven't encountered any problems when developing offline.
(Although I don't use external resources which are unavailable when there is no internet connection, so maybe you should try to pack the external resources into your project.)

Comment: This is the whole point of the question. He is looking for a way to patch the external resources without having to change everything when he switches between online/offline modes.